# Cannot get image url (stored as a file) to to display on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using Parse.com and JavaScript SDK

I've created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/jst34fe4/1/

The query runs and returns the current user object, as per the below screen shot part of that object is the url, which I want to display as an image. Currentlyno image is showing. I'm not sure why?

Please not the image is stored as a file in parse. I've read the parse document here, but that has'nt helped solve this. https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#files-retrieving

```
ProfilePic: {__type:File, name:tfss-fc2a6901-40a1-49d9-9044-3d4bcc42d7a1-danimage.jpg,…}
__type: "File"
name: "tfss-fc2a6901-40a1-49d9-9044-3d4bcc42d7a1-danimage.jpg"
**url: "http://files.parsetfss.com/0fc5cba8-caf7-4c81-aafc-36390888e497/tfss-fc2a6901-40a1-49d9-9044-3d4bcc42d7a1-danimage.jpg"**
```

[image]

[image: Object structure]

Comment: In the fiddle, the login does not work.

Comment: Can you give me detail? what bit is'nt working?

Comment: It throws 404, with this JSON response: `{"code":101,"error":"invalid login parameters"}` (Guess they haven't heard of 403 (: )

Comment: tweaked it, try now?

Comment: then please update the Fiddle link, it changes after updates

Comment: Ok done - http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/jst34fe4/1/

Comment: Okay, now it returns the expected JSON

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64024/discussion-between-dano007-and-meskobalazs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the URL as the following: `object.get('ProfilePic').url()`, because the `url` is a method, returning the `_url` field.

Also, you should delete `<div id="Image01"></div>`, as it casues an `id` collision. After these it works as expected.

#### Edit

I have updated the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jst34fe4/2/).